# DHCP assigns a new IP address when the Time Zone changes

Tags: linux, dhcp, dnsmasq, isc-dhcpd

I have a device linux-based. Through a webpage I can change the time zone runtime. This device takes the IP and NTP address from a DHCP.

Using two different servers I have two different behaviours:

- **dnsmasq** With the below configuration every time the change the time zone, after the reboot of the device, his **IP address remain the same**.

  ```
  dnsmasq --bind-interfaces --interface=eth0 \
          --dhcp-range=192.168.0.100,192.168.0.250,48h \
          --dhcp-option=42,192.168.0.4
  ```
- **dhcpd** (On Debian): With the below configuration `/etc/dhcp.conf` every time the change the time zone, after the reboot of the device, his **IP address is different**.

  ```
  option domain-name "domain.test.com";
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.104.1;
  option ntp-servers 192.168.104.1;

  default-lease-time 86400; #24h
  max-lease-time 172800; #48h

  ddns-update-style none;

  subnet 192.168.104.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
     range 192.168.104.50 192.168.104.150;
      option routers 192.168.104.1;
  }
  ```

The lease time is different but the time zone changes have been done with jumps of 12h max.

My question is: **Why the IP of device change?**
Thank you in advance for the explanation and/or indications.

Comment: Changing the time zone should not make any difference to DHCP. Odd.

Comment: I would suggest it's time to pull out a packet sniffer.

Comment: What leases exist for this MAC address in `dhcpd.leases`? My guess is that you'll find at least two.